# How can I find and count number of files matching a given string?

Tags: bash, counting

I want to find and count all the files on my system that begin with some string, say "foo", **using only one line** in bash.

I'm new to bash so I'd like to avoid scripting if possible - how can I do this using only simple bash commands and maybe piping in just one line?

So far I've been using `find / -name foo*`. This returns the list of files, but I don't know what to add to actually count the files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use

```
find / -type f -name 'foo*' | wc -l
```

- Use the single-quotes to prevent the shell from expanding the asterisk.
- Use `-type f` to include only files (not links or directories).
- `wc -l` means "word count, lines only."  Since `find` will list one file per line, this returns the number of files it found.

Answer (score 4):

`find / -name foo* | wc -l` should do it. Here is a link to [man wc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc). `wc -l` counts the number of lines

Comment: need to quote or escape the `*` so that the shell doesn't expand it before find sees it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe it into `wc`

```
find / -name foo * | wc -l
```